# Is interaction between a widget plugin and SonarQube server to do analysis possible?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

Specifically, I want to run some analysis on the issues generated and rules violated. So I want to design the system to have a few click actions in the web interface of sonar and initiate the analysis in the back-end. The reason for this is that the analyses are run only during some cases and I don't want the instance with my plugin to have additional load during each run.

Also if possible could you point me in the right direction?

I couldn't find anything on here. http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Web+API

Please note I have been searching this very recently and am also new to SonarQube.

Comment: Have you done anything in an attempt to solve your problem?

Comment: what is your version of SonarQube? – do you want to update the UI? – what are you trying to do?

Comment: SonarQube version is 6. Yes I want to update the UI after the analytics is complete and also display the status/progress of the analytics. So once I click on "Analyse X" the plugin should start classifying the issue types specified by me, the UI will show a pie chart that is updated continually, till the classification is complete.

Comment: Sorry, but what you're asking for is not possible...

Comment: Are you referring to the interaction between plugin and widget or doing the classification part in the backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SonarQube server is for performing analysis only. What I was looking was for the server to give the user access to control the analysis. But using independent plugins to do static analysis could work.

I solved this issue by splitting the plugin into

1. A plugin for doing inline analysis work (if a need for doing our own static analysis arises)
2. A WebApp to classify issues, listing them by projects, etc.

This approach seemed more attractive when after discussion, we decided that all functions we wanted out widget to do, our WebApp itself could do. From SonarQube version 6.2, the ruby APIs are going to be deprecated and so moving to a REST-based approach would give an enduring solution.